# campinglistformcontroller.js can't insert form in database trailhead

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, controller

I'm stuck at the last component Aura challenge,

I managed the challenge but when I try to insert a form in the database it makes me mistakes.

I tested with two submitform function
CampingListFormController.js

```
 ({
submitForm: function(component, event, helper) {    
    if(helper.validateItemForm(component)){
        // Create the new item
        var newItem = component.get("v.newItem");
        helper.addItem(component, newItem);
    }

},

submitFormm: function(component, event, helper) {
    var validExpense = component.find('campingform').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
        // Displays error messages for invalid fields
        inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
        return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
    }, true);
    // If we pass error checking, do some real work
    if(validExpense){
        // Create the new expense
        var newItem = component.get("v.newItem");
        helper.addItem(component, newItem);
    }
}

})
```

When i click in insert button :

> for the first function SubmitForm (with only one "m" at the end) i
>   have as error : Action failed: c:campingListForm$controller$submitForm
>   [Cannot read property 'get' of undefined] Failing descriptor:
>   {c:campingListForm$controller$submitForm}
>
> for the second function SubmitFormm (with two"m" at the end) i have as
>   error : Action failed: c:campingListForm$controller$submitFormm
>   [component.getItem is not a function] Failing descriptor:
>   {c:campingListForm$controller$submitFormm}

There is my campingListFormHelper.js

```
({
 addItem: function(component, newItem) {
 var addItem = component.getItem("addItem");
 addItem.setParams({ "item": item });
 addItem.fire();
        component.set("v.newItem",{ 'sobjectType': 'Camping_Item__c',
                'Name': '',
                'Quantity__c': 0,
                'Price__c': 0,
                'Packed__c': false });
},


    validateItemForm: function(component) {

          // Simplistic error checking
    var validItem = true;

    // Name must not be blank
    var nameField = component.find("itemname");
    var itemname = nameField.get("v.value");
    if ($A.util.isEmpty(itemname)){
        validItem = false;
        nameField.set("v.errors", [{message:"Item name can't be blank."}]);
    }
    else {
        nameField.set("v.errors", null);
    }

    // Quantity must not be blank
    var quantityField = component.find("quantity");
    var quantity = nameField.get("v.value");
    if ($A.util.isEmpty(quantity)){
        validItem = false;
        quantityField.set("v.errors", [{message:"Quantity can't be blank."}]);
    }
    else {
        quantityField.set("v.errors", null);
    }
    // Price must not be blank
    var priceField = component.find("price");
    var price = priceField.get("v.value");
    if ($A.util.isEmpty(price)){
        validItem = false;
        priceField.set("v.errors", [{message:"Price can't be blank."}]);
    }
    else {
        quantityField.set("v.errors", null);
    }
        return (validItem);

}
})
```

CampingListForm.cmp

```
<aura:component >

<aura:attribute name="newItem" type="Camping_Item__c"
                default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Camping_Item__c',
                         'Name': '',
                         'Quantity__c': 0,
                         'Price__c': 0,
                         'Packed__c': false }"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="addItem" type="c:addItemEvent"/>
<!-- CREATE NEW Campaing FORM -->
<form class="slds-form--stacked">

    <!-- For Name Field -->
    <lightning:input aura:id="campingform" label="Name"
                     name="expensename"
                     value="{!v.newItem.Name}"
                     required="true"/>
    <!-- For Quantity Field -->
    <lightning:input type="number" aura:id="campingform" label="Quantity"
                     name="expenseamount"
                     min="1"
                     value="{!v.newItem.Quantity__c}"
                     messageWhenRangeUnderflow="Enter minimum 1 Quantity"/>
    <!-- For Price Field -->
    <lightning:input aura:id="campingform" label="Price"
                     formatter="currency"
                     name="expenseclient"
                     value="{!v.newItem.Price__c}"
                     />
    <!-- For Check Box -->
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="campingform" label="Packed?"  
                     name="expreimbursed"
                     checked="{!v.newItem.Packed__c}"/>

    <lightning:button label="Create Camping" 
                      class="slds-m-top--medium"
                      variant="brand"
                      onclick="{!c.submitFormm}"/>
</form>
<!-- / CREATE NEW EXPENSE FORM -->

</aura:component>
```

Comment: Can you add code of your lightning component markup?

Comment: @RedDevil okey !

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues here. Fixing these will resolve your errors.

1. In `validateItemForm()` function which is called from your `submitForm()`, you are trying to do as below resulting an error because there is no `aura:id` with the value `itemname` on your component:

   ```
   var nameField = component.find("itemname");
   var itemname = nameField.get("v.value"); // you get the error because of this line
   // you will need to ensure that you fetch the correct attribute here
   ```
2. Then in the `addItem()` function, which is called from your `submitFormm()`, you have as below where it seems you are trying to get the event declared on your component. The syntax is incorrect here. There is no such function `getItem()` on a component.

   ```
   // this synxtax is incorrect; there is no function as getItem
   var addItem = component.getItem("addItem"); 

   // You are most likely trying to use component.get("v.addItem");
   ```